# Gradle task does not run properly

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project with 2 sub-projects 'restsanatan-server' and 'restsanatan-webapp.' When I clean and build the project, the task packageWebapp in restsanatan-server runs before assemble but however in the generated distributions, the WEB-INF.zip file doesn't appear. When I build again without cleaning, the zip is copied to the resources directory and built properly and I find the file in the distributions. What am I doing wrong?

Root build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

version "0.10.0"

project(':restsanatan-server').setVersion(version)
project(':restsanatan-webapp').setVersion("0.1.0")

task distZip(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn(":build")

    from file(project("restsanatan-server").buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/distributions")
    include("restsanatan-server-${version}.zip")
    include("restsanatan-server-shadow-${version}.zip")
    rename("restsanatan-server-${version}.zip", "RestSanatan-${version}.zip")
    rename("restsanatan-server-shadow-${version}.zip", "RestSanatan-fat-${version}.zip")
    into buildDir
}

task distJar(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn(":build")

    from file(project("restsanatan-server").buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/libs")
    include("restsanatan-server-${version}.jar")
    include("restsanatan-server-${version}-all.jar")
    rename("restsanatan-server-${version}.jar", "RestSanatan-${version}.jar")
    rename("restsanatan-server-${version}-all.jar", "RestSanatan-fat-${version}.jar")
    into buildDir
}

build {
    dependsOn(":restsanatan-server:build")
    dependsOn(":restsanatan-webapp:build")
}

build.finalizedBy(distZip)
build.finalizedBy(distJar)

clean {
    dependsOn(":restsanatan-server:clean")
    dependsOn(":restsanatan-webapp:clean")
}
```

restsanatan-server build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
}

group 'org.projectsanatan.restsanatan'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    metaFile = "restsanatan.meta"
    javaMainClass = "org.projectsanatan.restsanatan.Main"

    homePage = "https://github.com/ProjectSanatan/RestSanatan/README.md"
    repository = "https://github.com/ProjectSanatan/RestSanatan.git"

    webapp = rootProject.project(":restsanatan-webapp")
}

application {
    mainClassName = javaMainClass
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.8'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.8'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:11.0.9'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:11.0.8'
//    implementation 'es.moki.ratelimitj:ratelimitj-core:0.7.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20211205'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jetty-http:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:3.0.4'    
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.0.4'
//    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:3.1.0-M3'
    implementation 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0'
    implementation 'org.jline:jline:3.21.0'
    implementation 'org.jline:jline-console:3.21.0'
    implementation 'org.jline:jline-terminal:3.21.0'
    implementation 'org.jline:jline-reader:3.21.0'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
    implementation 'com.bucket4j:bucket4j-core:8.1.1'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.1.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.register('writeMeta') {
    Properties meta = new Properties()
    meta.setProperty("version", version)
    meta.setProperty("home_page", homePage)
    meta.setProperty("repository", repository)

    File f = new File(projectDir.getAbsolutePath(), metaFile)
    if (!f.exists()) f.createNewFile()

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f)
    meta.store(os, "restsanatan-server packaging metadata")
    os.close()

    copy {
        from projectDir
        include metaFile
        into file(buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/resources/main/org/projectsanatan/restsanatan")
    }

    f.delete()
}

// 
task packageWebapp(type: Copy) {
//    mustRunAfter(writeMeta)

    from file(webapp.buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/distributions/RestSanatan-WEBAPP-${webapp.version}.zip")
    into file(buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/resources/main/org/projectsanatan/restsanatan")
    rename "RestSanatan-WEBAPP-${webapp.version}.zip", "WEB-INF.zip"
}

assemble.dependsOn(writeMeta)
assemble.dependsOn(packageWebapp)
//jar.dependsOn(packageWebapp)
//shadowJar.dependsOn(packageWebapp)

run {
    dependsOn(assemble)
}
```

restsanatan-webapp build.gradle

````
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

group "org.projectsanatan.restsanatan"

ext {
    metaFile = "restsanatan-webapp.meta"
}

task writeMeta() {
    Properties meta = new Properties()
    meta.setProperty("version", version)

    File f = new File(projectDir.getAbsolutePath(), metaFile)
    if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile()

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f)
    meta.store(os, "restsanatan-webapp packaging metadata")
    os.close()

    copy {
        from projectDir
        include metaFile
        into buildDir
    }

    f.delete()
}

task dist(type: Zip) {
    from "build/generated"
    into "RestSanatan-WEBAPP-${project.version}.zip"
}

assemble {
    mkdir("build/generated")
    copy {
        from "src"
        into "build/generated/public"
        include "**"
    }
    copy {
        from "views"
        into "build/generated/views"
        include "**"
    }
}

//build.dependsOn(clean)
build.finalizedBy(dist)```
````

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you make a MCVE?

Comment: @Jorn I don't know what is a MCVE, sorry.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example